# new WP_query using custom fields

Tags: wp-query, custom-field

I am trying to query child posts from two parents (that part is working fine),

... but now I want to exclude posts that have a meta_key of 'feature' with a meta_value of '1'

Using the Codex reference I've tried a couple of ways to write this, not working.

Here's what I've written thus far, I believe I'm close, but need help.
Thank you!

```
<?php
    $argsthis = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'post_parent__in' => array(10,11),
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
            'key'     => 'feature',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '!=',
            ),
        )
    );
?>
```

and I've tried, simply (w exact same result as above):

```
<?php
    $argsthis = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '5',
    'post_parent__in' => array(10,11),
    'meta_key'     => 'feature',
    'meta_value'   => '1',
    'meta_compare' => '!=',
            ),
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you seeing posts with that meta_value in your results? Are you seeing no results?

Comment: instead of showing my intention of all child pages of post_parent__in 10 and 11 except the page with custom field of meta_key=feature and meta_value=1; the page only displays one page from post_parent=10.

Comment: I would start by double- (or triple-!) checking that you have posts meeting those criteria. Then look in your database and see how the meta_value is being saved. Is it a string? An integer? Boolean even?

Comment: Tripled checked, posts meet criteria. feature 1 and feature 2 query works as ir should for another query set up on the same page -- and my query for this issue works as it should except when I try to filter out feature 1.

Comment: OK, not sure what I'm looking at when checking the db --
but under postmeta table: meta_id is bigint, post_id is bigint, meta_key is varchar, meta_value is longtext. So I'm using characters for key and a number for value (which is OK for longtext?) and as I mentioned when querying for feature 1 and 2 (for another wp_query on same pg but not the query in this question) I use the same values for meta_key and meta_value an that query works fine.

Comment: 1) Can you add the query that *is* working? 2) You definitely want to use `meta_query`. `meta_key`/`meta_value` is half-deprecated in that it's only used in conjunction with the `orderby` argument now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works in my query:

```
<?php
    $argsfeature = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'meta_key' => 'featuring',
    'meta_value' => '1' 
    );

    ?>
```

and this query works:

```
<?php
  $argsarticles = array(
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'post_type' => 'page',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'posts_per_page' => '5',
   'post_parent__in' => array(10,11)
    );
 ?>
```

what isn't working is "rewriting" the 2nd query listed above where I can get the child pages of 10 and 11, BUT NOT the pages that have already been pulled from the "featuring 1" query  - the first query listed above.

Thank you so much for the help.